# Yii + PDO_DBLIB + SQL Server

Tags: php, sql-server, sql-server-2008, yii, freetds

My website based on yii framework and I work with SQL Server (on Windows) under linux using pdo_dblib + freetds.

**My FreeTDS config:**

```
[egServer70]
        host = my server ip address
        port = 1433
        tds version = 8.0
        client charset = UTF-8
```

Connection is fine. Website uses UTF-8, and SQL Servercolumns used `nvarchar, ntext` etc. types.

When I insert some cyrillic text into database, it inserts like this "????????????????????".

With english text inserts well.

When I select data where cyrillic text already have, it displays normal.

So problem only when I try `INSERT` cyrillic text.

Anyone know how resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following

```
INSERT INTO Sentences (LangText) VALUES (N'Поиск')
```

(Note the "N" qualifier on the constant)

for additional info, read [Here](http://www.dbforums.com/microsoft-sql-server/1629581-inserting-retrieving-cyrillic-characters.html)